# How xpath works internally?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

When I Write a  XPath then from where does the browser fetch the XML of page,In short how browser works internally with xpath.

I am learning selenium and I am using xpath to identify WebElements.

Answer (score 1):

In general, an **XPath** expression specifies a pattern that selects a set of **XML nodes**. **XSLT** templates then use those patterns when applying transformations.

(XPointer, on the other hand, adds mechanisms for defining a point or a range so that XPath expressions can be used for addressing).

The nodes in an **XPath** expression refer to more than just **elements**. They also refer to **text** and **attributes**, among other things. In fact, the **XPath** specification defines an **abstract document model**.

For more you can refer this link :  [How xpath works internally](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/xslt/xpath.html)

Comment: *"...XPath expression refer to more than just elements"*. Actually this is not applicable to Selenium as in Selenium XPath can fetch elements ONLY

Comment: @Andersson : Yes, you are right. If we are talking in selenium context only. Basically those xpath expression will be fetched from DOM, with the help of methods which xpath processor has ,  as Michael explained it.

Answer (score 1):

In general an XPath processor takes as input (a) an XPath expression, and (b) a node used as the context node; it evaluates that expression against that context node, and returns a result to the calling application.

So an API for invoking XPath will generally look like

```
result = xpath.eval(expression, contextNode)
```

or perhaps

```
result = contextNode.evalXPath(expression)
```

or perhaps

```
result = xpath.compile(expression).eval(contextNode)
```

In a web browser environment the contextNode might implicitly be set to the HTML page by default.

In practice APIs for invoking XPath have additional complexities, for example to allow the namespace context to be set, and to allow external variables/parameters to be bound to values.

Comment: can you please share any reference document of xpath processor.

Comment: You might find my book useful (XSLT 2.0 and XPath 2.0 Programmer's Reference, published by Wiley). I try to explain the general concepts in some detail, but whether it's at the right level for you is hard to judge.